# ImportRange is not updating automatically

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

have this problem that my importrange function is not updating automatically. I did transfer it successfully but whenever I add data from the sheet where the data came from, it just not automatically updating to another sheet where I copy it.

This are the links for both sheets.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1koo5Qz5DtfSlyctxicXI3vXG7ftvlkCJU_oiSiOdsZA/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rvUGMiPtuVJ4uypUaSPOFX0JEyvdWUrjR5RhufsEx-4/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you so much! I'll be in the sheet if you have any confusion.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the bug. Could you screen the error process?

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/125980666

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: It really didn't work on my sheet. I think I need to put it manually, Thank you BorisBaublys and MattKing